# Free / open source tool to flatten PDFs?

Tags: pdf, pdf-viewer, pdf-editor

Looking for above-mentioned tool to work with PDFs. Following functions are desired:

1. Draw lines, rectangles, circles for annotations
2. Include comments (as in actual text onto the PDF, not speech bubbles)
3. Permanently affix signatures
4. Permanently affix other logos

So far, points (1) to (3) can be achieved with Adobe Reader but I cannot find a reasonably easy solution for (4). If I have to, I don't mind working with 2 programs although 1 program for all the above would be highly desirable.
Much thanks in advance for any recommendations.

@RockPaperLizard: By flatten, I mean to make elements (such as points 3 and 4) permanently part of the PDF file and not removable. Of course, if the reader wishes, they can always print screen the document to extract the image but what I have inserted into the flattened PDF should stay there unless a crude method such as putting a whitebox over the area is employed to block the image.
@Izzy: To run on Windows (7, 8, 10 etc) would be sufficient. Preferably free / open source per subject, otherwise I would have to write a paper to the company for approval. In such case, I much prefer the software to be under perpetual licensing unless the annual increment is small.

Comment: What do you mean by "flatten"?

Comment: And what OS shall it run on? What is your price limit?